# does c++ allows hoisting or is it compiler specific ? even if

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, extern, linkage

So i was looking through various questions to prepare for my interview that's up tomorrow and came across extern keyword, i understand that extern keyword specifies to allocate memory for a variable which is part of another program(dont know where to use) but the real doubt is,

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;


int main()
{
    extern int a;
    cout<<a;
    
    return 0;
}

int a=20;


output:
 20
```

i wonder how this works? even if hoisting works in c++ , i know a bit of JS hoisting like even if the declaration of a as int a is done first and assignment is done later , the output is ought to be a value a garbage value....

Comment: `extern int a;` is *"just"* a declaration.

Comment: C++ does not have hoisting. What you're seeing is that global variables such as `a` are initialized before `main` is called.

Comment: so when do we need to use extern in our program ?

Comment: In this context, the `extern` keyword tells the compiler that the variable exists with [*external linkage*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#external_linkage) somewhere in a [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Answer (score 0):

For this block scope declaration

```
extern int a;
```

the compiler searches a previous declaration of the name `a`  in the global namespace that to determine whether it has external or internal linkage. If the compiler does not find the previous declaration it thinks that the variable `a` refers to a variable defined in the global namespace with external linkage.

And indeed there is a definition of the variable in the global namespace

```
int a=20;
```

So the two declarations refer to the same object defined in the global namespace.

From the C++ 17 Standard (6.5 Program and linkage)

> 2 A name is said to have linkage when it might denote the same object,
> reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name
> introduced by a declaration in another scope:

and

> 6 The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a
> variable declared by a block scope extern declaration have linkage. If
> there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the
> same name and type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost
> enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration declares that
> same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If
> there is more than one such matching entity, the program is
> ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope
> entity receives external linkage. If, within a translation unit, the
> same entity is declared with both internal and external linkage, the
> program is ill-formed.

That is a declaration in a block scope with the storage class specifier `extern` does not define a new object. It refers to an object with the same name defined in the enclosing namespace with an internal or external linkage.

Comment: so in this particular program extern int a thinks that int a is a part of it ?
what if in a program i have like , int a and extern int a being declared inside that same block ? for extern int a it must declare in global namespace and int a will also exist ? with different levels of scope ?

Comment: @anyman it means that the both declarations refer to the same object with external linkage.

Comment: boss ,can you give me a good blog to read about this 
lets say if i have a block within that block, first i create a variable named int a; and then next to that declare extern int a but why does this flag an error for redeclaration ?
because extern int a will search for a in global namespace, wait, does that global namespace mean the current program or anyother namespace thats being included using "using namespace xyz" ? if a variable called a exists in xyz then both int a and then extern int a will exist :?

Comment: @anyman It is because the same variable is declared as having no linkage and as having external linkage.

Comment: so how do i create a linkage, can you give me an example to understand it better

Comment: @anyman Your program in the question is such an example.